# Condition on existence of solution for system of inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> Let $a,b,c,x,y,z>0$. Under which condition of $a,b,c$ there will exists some $x,y,z>0$ such that 
>   \begin{equation} \begin{cases} 
> x - \dfrac{a}{2} - c \left( 4x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \right) & > 0 \\ 
> y - b - c \left( 4x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \right) & > 0 \\ 
> z - c \left( 4x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \right) & > 0  
> \end{cases} \end{equation}

I know that $a,b,c$ should be somehow sufficiently small. But how small is it in a precise way?

My first observation is that we can multiply the first inequality by $2$ to consider instead the following system
\begin{equation} \begin{cases} 
x' - a - 2 c \left( \left( x' \right) ^2 + y^2 + z^2 \right) & > 0 \\ 
y - b - c \left( \left( x' \right) ^2 + y^2 + z^2 \right) & > 0 \\ 
z - c \left( \left( x' \right) ^2 + y^2 + z^2 \right) & > 0  
\end{cases} \end{equation}
Then if we consider $U := \left( x' , y , z \right)$ where $x',y,z>0$ and $x'=2x$. We got something like
\begin{equation}
\left\lVert U \right\rVert ^{2} < \dfrac{1}{c} \min \left\lbrace \dfrac{1}{2} \left( x'-a \right) , y-b , z \right\rbrace .
\end{equation}
So the solution $U := \left( x' , y , z \right)$ should have the norm square less than some quatities which related to each components. Perhaps there should be some geometrical explaination for this or I simply just going in the wrong direction?

Comment: You made mistake multiplying by 2.  Why did 4 disappear?

Comment: What is $R_{++}^3?$

Comment: @WilliamElliot $R_{++}^{3}$ means that $x,y,z>0$. The second system is repsect to $x',y,z$ with $x' = 2x$. That's why $4$ disappear. I made some change to clearify

Comment: You meant $(R_+)^3$.

Comment: Yes! Sorry for that confusion.